# The service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

Tags: c#, windows-services

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller;
    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        // Here we can set properties on serviceProcessInstaller
        //or register event handlers
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;

        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = MyNewService.MyServiceName;
        this.Installers.AddRange(new Installer[] {
            serviceProcessInstaller, serviceInstaller });
    }

    private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}



public partial class MyNewService : ServiceBase
{

    FileSystemWatcher myWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\Desktop\\demo");
    public const string MyServiceName = "MyNewService";
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher = null;


    public MyNewService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
           | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName
           | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    }
    //private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;
    //    Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}", e.FullPath, wct.ToString());
    //}
    protected void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
            { Console.WriteLine("Directory Exists"); }            // a directory
            else { Console.WriteLine("File"); }
            // a file
        }
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;


        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Users\\Ahmed\\Desktop\\demo", "*.txt");

        //Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
        //the renaming of files or directories.
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        watcher.Dispose();

        LogEvent("Monitoring Stopped");
    }

    void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string mgs = string.Format("File {0} | {1}",e.FullPath, e.ChangeType);
        LogEvent(mgs);
    }

    void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        string log = string.Format("{0} | Renamed from {1}",
                                   e.FullPath, e.OldName);
        LogEvent(log);
    }
    private void LogEvent(string message)
    {
        string eventSource = "File Monitor Service";
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        message = dt.ToLocalTime() + ": " + message;

        EventLog.WriteEntry(eventSource, message);
    }

    private void eventLog1_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}


static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyNewService() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new MyNewService() });
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem Solved
this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;
in the OnStart() method is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;` should be in the Constructor, not the OnStart method. The constructor will set it for each instance, but it throws an exception because the service is already considered running by the time OnStart is called.

> The ServiceName identifies the service to the Service Control Manager. The value of this property must be identical to the name recorded for the service in the ServiceInstaller.ServiceName property of the corresponding installer class. In code, the ServiceName of the service is usually set in the main() function of the executable.

--[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.SERVICEPROCESS.SERVICEBASE.SERVICENAME%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)