# Windows Service unexplainably stops when started in SCM

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am making a Windows service in Visual Studio using C#. When I run the program from the command line it works as expected. No exceptions get thrown or anything like that, and the event log get's written to like normal. Here is my entry method.

```
var service = new CSFolderWatcher();
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    service.CallStart(args);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop program");
    Console.Read();
    service.CallStop();
}
else
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new CSFolderWatcher() });
}
```

However, when I go into the SCM to start the service, a box immediately pops up that says "The CS Folder Watcher service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs." Nothing gets written to the event log at all. Here is my onStart code:

```
internal void CallStart(string[] args) { OnStart(args); }
internal void CallStop() { OnStop(); }
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;

    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    this.destfolder = Properties.Settings.Default.DestinationFolder;
    this.watchfolder = Properties.Settings.Default.WatchFolder;
    this.watchfilter = Properties.Settings.Default.WatchFilter;
    LogEvent(this.ServiceName + " starting" + "\r\n" +
        "Destination folder: " + this.destfolder + "\r\n" +
        "Watch Folder: " + this.watchfolder + "\r\n" +
        "Watch Filter: " + this.watchfilter + "\r\n" + 
        "OnStart args: " + string.Join(", ", args));

    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher with the path
    //and text file filter
    try { watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(watchfolder, watchfilter); }
    catch (Exception e) { LogEvent(e.ToString()); throw; }

    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = Properties.Settings.Default.WatchSubdirectories;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                         | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                         | NotifyFilters.FileName
                         | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

Here's the code for LogEvent:

```
private void LogEvent(string message)
{
    string eventSource = MyServiceName;
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    dt = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    message = dt.ToLocalTime() + ": " + message;

    Console.WriteLine(message);
    EventLog.WriteEntry(eventSource, message);
}
```

Comment: `Properties.Settings.Default.DestinationFolder` what is the folder path it's looking for on the target / running machine outside of your local..? are you sure that the paths even exist the same as in your local environment.. also what are the rights that the Service has on the Target Machine..? could this be a rights / permissions issue ..? if not could this be a `Path` issue..? also if this is a `FileSystemWatcher` service why are you calling stop..? shouldn't this run always and have some manual intervention to stop it..?

Comment: CallStart and CallStop are only for running from the console, because I couldn't access the OnStart and OnStop methods directly. So yes, that's just the OnStop method that is supposed to be there.

Comment: What do you mean by that it could be a PATH issue?

Comment: what is the `File Path` on your local machine that you have setup here `Properties.Settings.Default.DestinationFolder` and on the production or target machine is there a FilePath that exist the same on there.. the same question for the other file path `WatchFolder` personally I would add some `if (!Directory.Exist(this.destfolder)){then create it}`

Comment: This is all on one machine. Everything is still development. And I can't event get OnStart to run, so I'm not sure why DestinationFolder even matters. It's not used here. But the folders do exist.

Comment: you have this being used in your code `this.destfolder` so not sure what you mean when you say not being used here.. sounds like you need to really debug the code and step thru and see what's really throwing the error also add some better logging locally for debug purposes vs trying to rely on the Event log for right now..

Comment: Oh. Now I follow you. Those are settings in the local class, but I'll check that out.

Comment: also show the Method of where the code is being called / ran from as well in regards to this line `ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[]` also if you want to write all entries to the eventlog you should set or check [AutoLog Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.autolog(v=vs.110).aspx) && http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart(v=vs.110).aspx [Service BaseClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I found it. LogEvent seemed to be working. The second line in OnStart is the problem. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot change service name when the service is running.

Comment: Look at this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498060/the-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped-some-services-stop-autom)

Comment: `Arlen Beiler` so hard to tell what your class should or should not be doing without seeing the whole Class Structure and what you are Inheriting from here is a step by step tutorial as well you can follow and stub in your working code where needed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3938/Creating-a-C-Service-Step-by-Step-Lesson-I

Comment: OK, thanks. Thanks for your help. Actually, I got it. So thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turns out to be that you can't set the ServiceName property from the OnStart method. `this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;` should be in the constructor instead, as it seems like it *is* necessary to set it.

> The ServiceName identifies the service to the Service Control Manager. The value of this property must be identical to the name recorded for the service in the ServiceInstaller.ServiceName property of the corresponding installer class. In code, the ServiceName of the service is usually set in the main() function of the executable.

--[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.SERVICEPROCESS.SERVICEBASE.SERVICENAME%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)